# how to turn off airplane mode

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 20.04, hp, airplane-mode

I am a beginner to ubuntu and linux. I have installed 20.04 alongside windows 8.1. My laptop is HP Pavilion g6-2200ee notebook.
My problem is that I cannot turn off airplane mode due to which I cannot connect to wifi.
But I can connect the wifi in windows as the airplane mode is off.
I have a switch for wifi its F12, I tried to do Fn+F12 but still no response, even tried from the terminal by using the code given in some of the answer here but still no luck.
Please help me out.

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
        DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 
        Combo Ad 
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1X1 Wi- 
        Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
0: phy0: Wirless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: do you have a wifi switch? Did you try F12 with no Fn?

Comment: Two things I found: 1. try booting into Windows, turning off Fast Boot and turning on wifi, shutting down, and reboot into Ubuntu, or 2. try resetting your BIOS.

Comment: yes I do have a wifi switch it is F12, yes have tried F12 with no Fn it show airplane mode on. how do I reset my BIOS

Comment: when you boot your laptop, press whichever key you need to enter bios (probably f10 for hp laptops, but try other fn keys, esc, or del if that doesn't work, or google it) and navigate the settings until you get to something that looks like "set all settings to default" or something like that. It really depends on your machine where that is exactly.

Comment: ok will try and let u know, thanks

Comment: hi, i have reset to default and even i have removed window and installed ubuntu on my laptop, so now i have only ubuntu on my laptop, but still i am facing the same issue. at present i am connecting net through usb tethering. kindly give me some solution.

Comment: hi, suppose i upgrade to the new version, will my issue be resolved.

Comment: i upgraded by system to 22.04, but the issue has not been resolved. anyone please help